# simple var assignment for not set variables in python

Tags: python

I very often come along the need to build statements like this in python:

```
kwargs['help'] = '' if 'help' not in kwargs else kwargs['help']
```

and I wonder if this is pythonic way to do this. I dont like the repetitive else part, but if I do

```
if 'help' not in kwargs:
    kwargs['help'] = ''
```

this would be less repetitive but not really less verbose because its on two lines. And I really like in the first example, that it starts with the var assignment (which is the important thing that is happening here)

The problem is, I cant work with the and/or shortcircuiting when assigning variables

```
var or var = ''
```

wont work.

I would love to have something simple like:

```
var = '' if not var
```

so just without the else statement. But this is not implemented in python, so would be my way (first example) be considered pythonic, or should I use the two line if clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of handling the `kwargs` issues is a one-liner:

```
kwargs.setdefault('help', '')
```

`setdefault` happens to return the value (which you ignore), but it does exactly what you want; nothing if the value is set, set the default otherwise.

For general variables, you can't handle "unsetness" nicely, but if you're trying to set `var` only if it's falsy, then:

```
 var = var or ''
```

will work just fine; `or` evaluates to the last expression evaluated, so it will produce any truthy value of `var` by preference, and `''` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you know `kwargs` is `dict` you might use `.get` method, so instead of:

```
kwargs['help'] = '' if 'help' not in kwargs else kwargs['help']
```

you might do

```
kwargs['help'] = kwargs.get('help', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setdefault` method

`kwargs.setdefault('help', '')`

or you could use a `collections.defaultdict(str)`.